# Fourier transform with cuFFT, are complex to complex more efficient?

Tags: cuda, fft, cufft

I'm writing a code that integrates a PDE in time in Fourier space, and I'm doing so in CUDA/C++.

There is one real valued array I need to evolve in time.

I've written the code in two different ways, but following the exact same logic.

In one version I simply define all all arrays as complex valued, and do complex to complex transforms. I make sure that I keep the one that is meant to be real valued being so by setting it's imaginary part to 0 every time step (to account for small errors accumulating in its imaginary part).

```
float *real;
cufftComplex *fourier;
...
for (int t = 0; t < totalTime; t++)
{
   cufftEcexC2R(plan1, fourier, real);
   // do some calculations
   cufftExecR2C(plan2, real, fourier);
   integrate<<<blocks, threads>>>(fourier, other parameters);
}
```

In the other version I have an array of floats for the real valued array, and a complex one for its fourier transform, and do complex-to-real and real-to-complex transforms.

```
cufftComplex *real;
cufftComplex *fourier;
...
for (int t = 0; t < totalTime; t++)
{
   cufftEcexC2C(plan, fourier, real, CUFFT_INVERSE);
   // do some calculations
   cufftExecC2C(plan, real, fourier, CUFFT_FORWARD); // only need one plan in this case
   integrate<<<blocks, threads>>>(fourier, other parameters);
}
```

I was under the impression that this second choice would be faster and more memory efficient. I understand it's more memory efficient because both arrays are half the size, one is real instead of complex, and the complex one only stores N/2+1 values. I have observed however that the first option is consistently, in my case and with my hardware, about 20% faster. (See minimal reproducible example below)

Is this expected to be so? Are complex-to-complex transforms faster computationally than real-to-complex or complex-to-real?

Minimal reproducible example. The following two codes are fully compilable. The one involving the real to complex and viceversa, in my hardware, takes about 1.1 to 1.2 second in average. The one involving complex to complex takes about 0.9 in average. The actual program runs for very long so this small difference is very noticeable in the larger program.

The `helper_cuda.h` and `helper_functions.h` are not necessary to compile them, although they can be found in the `Common` directory of the samples that come with the cuda toolkit.

This one uses only complex-to-complex

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <random>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <complex.h>


#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cufft.h>
#include <cufftXt.h>
#include <helper_cuda.h>
#include <helper_functions.h>

using namespace std;

void printProgressbar(int t, int Nsteps, int length)
{
    int progress = t*100/Nsteps;
    int sprogress = t*length/Nsteps;
    int left = length - sprogress - 1;
    cout << "Progress [";
    for (int i = 0; i < sprogress; i++)
        cout << "=";
    cout << ">";
    for (int i = 0; i < left; i++)
        cout << " ";
    cout << "] " << progress << "%   \r";
    cout.flush();
}

int main()
{
    int N = 128;
    int Nsteps = 50000;
    int numberofsnaps = 5;
    int plot_steps = Nsteps/numberofsnaps;

    cufftComplex *phi_host = new cufftComplex[N*N];
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());
    uniform_real_distribution<> dis(-0.01,0.01);
    for (int i = 0; i < N*N; i++)
    {
        phi_host[i].x = (float)dis(gen);
        phi_host[i].y = 0.0f;
    }

    // Device arrays
    cufftComplex *phi_real;
    cufftComplex *phi_comp;

    cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&phi_real), N * N * sizeof(cufftComplex));
    cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&phi_comp), N * N * sizeof(cufftComplex));

    cufftHandle plan_c2c;
    cufftPlan2d(&plan_c2c, N, N, CUFFT_C2C);

    cudaMemcpy(phi_real, phi_host, N * N * sizeof(cufftComplex), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cufftExecC2C(plan_c2c, phi_real, phi_comp, CUFFT_FORWARD);

    for (int t = 0; t < Nsteps; t++)
    {
        // Output data
        if (t % plot_steps == 0)
        {
            printProgressbar(t,Nsteps,25);
            cudaMemcpy(phi_host, phi_real, N * N * sizeof(cufftComplex), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        }
        cufftExecC2C(plan_c2c, phi_comp, phi_real, CUFFT_INVERSE);
        cufftExecC2C(plan_c2c, phi_real, phi_comp, CUFFT_FORWARD);
    }
    cout << "Progress [========================>] 100%" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This one uses real-to-complex and viceversa

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <random>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <complex.h>


#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cufft.h>
#include <cufftXt.h>
#include <helper_cuda.h>
#include <helper_functions.h>
using namespace std;

void printProgressbar(int t, int Nsteps, int length)
{
    int progress = t*100/Nsteps;
    int sprogress = t*length/Nsteps;
    int left = length - sprogress - 1;
    cout << "Progress [";
    for (int i = 0; i < sprogress; i++)
        cout << "=";
    cout << ">";
    for (int i = 0; i < left; i++)
        cout << " ";
    cout << "] " << progress << "%   \r";
    cout.flush();
}

int main()
{
    int N = 128;
    int Np = N/2 + 1;
    int Nsteps = 50000;
    int numberofsnaps = 5;
    int plot_steps = Nsteps/numberofsnaps;

    float *phi_host = new float[N*N];
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());
    uniform_real_distribution<> dis(-0.01,0.01);
    for (int i = 0; i < N*N; i++)
    {
        phi_host[i] = (float)dis(gen);
    }

    // Device arrays
    float *phi_real;
    cufftComplex *phi_comp;

    cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&phi_real), N * N * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&phi_comp), N * Np * sizeof(cufftComplex));

    cufftHandle plan_r2c, plan_c2r;
    cufftPlan2d(&plan_r2c, N, N, CUFFT_R2C);
    cufftPlan2d(&plan_c2r, N, N, CUFFT_C2R);

    cudaMemcpy(phi_real, phi_host, N * N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cufftExecR2C(plan_r2c, phi_real, phi_comp);

    for (int t = 0; t < Nsteps; t++)
    {
        // Output data
        if (t % plot_steps == 0)
        {
            printProgressbar(t,Nsteps,25);
            cudaMemcpy(phi_host, phi_real, N * N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        }
        cufftExecC2R(plan_c2r, phi_comp, phi_real);
        cufftExecR2C(plan_r2c, phi_real, phi_comp);
    }
    cout << "Progress [========================>] 100%" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A real-to-complex transform should be faster than a corresponding complex to complex forward transform.  A complex to real transform should be faster than a corresponding complex to complex inverse transform.   If that were not the case, a very significant motivation for these special handling cases would disappear. There's not enough information here to explain why you might be seeing something different.  Performance questions require a full [mcve], in my opinion, to have a reasonable chance of explanation.

Comment: In principle, the real-to-half-complex transform is faster because it deals with half the data and does about half the computations. But I don’t know about this CUDA implementation.

Comment: @RobertCrovella You're right, thank you for the tip. I've included a very barebones reproducible example that shows a similar speed difference.

Comment: windows or linux?  CUDA version? GPU you are running on?: How are you measuring time?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Linux, CUDA v12, GTX1050. I'm measuring time by simply running `time ./program`, and I'm compiling them with `nvcc -O2 file.cu -lm -lcufft -o program`

Comment: I can't explain it.  Looking at the profiler, each FFT launches two kernels.  In the case of the C2C/C2C sequence, we have 4 kernels and in the case of the C2R/R2C sequence there are 4 kernels.  Based on the profiler, the 4 kernels for the C2C/C2C sequence are indeed slightly shorter in duration than the 4 kernels for the C2R/R2C sequence.  You might wish to [file a bug](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-report-a-bug/67911) to have the CUFFT development team investigate.  I will say that these FFT sizes are quite small, so the corresponding kernels are less than 10us each.

Comment: When I make `N` 512, according to my testing the performance reverses.  The C2R/R2C becomes somewhat faster.  There might be some overhead to the C2R/R2C kernels that is not amortized out for really small problem sizes.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Understood. Thanks a lot for your help and for taking the time!